# glReadPixels store x, y values

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to store pixel data by using glReadPixels, but so far I managed to only store it one pixel at a time. I'm not sure if this is the way to go. I currently have this:

```
unsigned char pixels[3];
glReadPixels(50,50, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

What would be a good way to store it in an array, so that I can get the values like this:

```
pixels[20][50][0]; // x=20 y=50 -> R value
pixels[20][50][1]; // x=20 y=50 -> G value
pixels[20][50][2]; // x=20 y=50 -> B value
```

I guess I could simple put it in a loop:

```
for ( all pixels on Y axis )
{
    for ( all pixels in X axis )
    {
        unsigned char pixels[width][height][3];
        glReadPixels(x,y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels[x][y]);
    }
}
```

But I have the feeling that there must be a much better way to do this. But I do however need my array to be like I described above the code. So would the for loop idea be good, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glReadPixels` simply returns bytes in the order `R, G, B, R, G, B, ...` (based on your setting of `GL_RGB`) from the **bottom left of the screen going up to the top right**. [From the OpenGL documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml):

> glReadPixels returns pixel data from the frame buffer, starting with
>   the pixel whose lower left corner is at location (x, y), into client
>   memory starting at location data. Several parameters control the
>   processing of the pixel data before it is placed into client memory.
>   These parameters are set with three commands: glPixelStore,
>   glPixelTransfer, and glPixelMap. This reference page describes the
>   effects on glReadPixels of most, but not all of the parameters
>   specified by these three commands.

The overhead of calling `glReadPixels` thousands of times will most likely take a noticeable amount of time (depends on the window size, I wouldn't be surprised if the loop took 1-2 seconds).

It is recommended that you only call `glReadPixels` once and store it in a byte array of size `(width - x) * (height - y) * 3`. From there you can either reference a pixel's component location with `data[(py * width + px) * 3 + component]` where `px` and `py` are the pixel locations you want to look up, and `component` being the R, G, or B components of the pixel.

If you absolutely **must** have it in a 3-dimensional array, you can write some code to rearrange the 1d array after the `glReadPixels` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll define pixel array like: this:

```
unsigned char pixels[MAX_Y][MAX_X][3];
```

And the you'll access it like this:

```
pixels[y][x][0] = r;
pixels[y][x][1] = g;
pixels[y][x][2] = b;
```

Then you'll be able to read pixels with one glReadPixels call:

```
glReadPixels(left, top, MAX_Y, MAX_X, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare a simple one dimensional array in a struct and use operator overloading for convenient subscript notation

```
struct Pixel2d
{
    static const int SIZE = 50;
    unsigned char& operator()( int nCol,  int nRow, int RGB)
    {
        return pixels[ ( nCol* SIZE + nRow) * 3 + RGB];
    }

    unsigned char pixels[SIZE * SIZE * 3 ];
};

int main()
{

    Pixel2d p2darray;
    glReadPixels(50,50, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &p.pixels);

    for( int i = 0; i < Pixel2d::SIZE ; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < Pixel2d::SIZE ; ++j )
        {
            unsigned char rpixel = p2darray(i , j , 0);
            unsigned char gpixel = p2darray(i , j , 1);
            unsigned char bpixel = p2darray(i , j , 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are reading a 50*50 pixel in one shot and using `operator()( int nCol,  int nRow, int RGB)` operator provides the needed convenience. For performance reasons you don't want to make too many `glReadPixels` calls